# Multiple t tests or something else?

Tags: anova, t-test, spss, multiple-comparisons

I have shown my respondents eight short films and asked them to rate the emotions that each film caused. Under each short film, I asked the respondents to rate on a scale of 1-5 how much of each emotion they felt when watching the film. There were six emotions to rate under each film. Four of the films are uneventful and four are dramatic, and I would like to assess if the four dramatic films cause more emotions overall than the "boring" ones. What would be the best way to do the comparison?

Comment: If you are interested in dramatic versus uneventful in general rather than your specific 4 dramatic versus your 4 uneventful, you should include "film" as a random effect.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have a block experiment with subjects as blocks and films as treatments. If you can fit that block model for each emotion you measured, then it appears the question you ask could be addressed by estimating and testing a single contrast with coefficients `[-1, -1, -1, -1, +1, +1, +1, +1] / 4`, (re-ordered as necessary -- I'm assuming the first 4 are boring and the last 4 are dramatic), which will compare the average rating for the dramatic films minus the average rating for the undramatic films.

I see the SPSS tag, and it has been so many decades since I've used that program that I can't help in the particulars of doing it with that software.

I hope you randomized the order of films differently for each subject. If not, the differences among the films could be due in part to the order in which they were presented, and there is no way of knowing with much certainty what those effects are.